# OSX terminal script - Try to open all files in directory

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, directory

I have some video files in a directory which can't be opened. The problem is that some of them have been wrongly transcoded, so they can't be opened with QuickTime.

What I was wondering is if there is some kind of script I could write that would read through all the files in a directory and try to open them with QuickTime, and if they can't be opened, to move them or do something else.

My actual file directory would be something like this:

```
--Main folder
---Subfolder
-----video.mov
-----video.mov
------Sub-Subfolder
--------video.mov
--------video.mov
---Subfolder
-----video.mov
-----video.mov
------Sub-Subfolder
--------video.mov
(...) and so on
```

I hope I've explained it well so you can understand it... If someone could help me, I'd appreciate it so much.

Thanks!

Comment: Looping through all the files in a folder is easy, use the `find` command. The hard part is determining whether QuickTime is able to open them. GUI applications don't return an error code to the shell that indicates whether they were successful. What you need is a command that tells whether file file is a valid movie file.

Comment: maybe you can use ffmpeg, to convert the files, and watch for AVERROR_INVALIDDATA which represent conversion failure

Comment: an example : ffmpeg -v error -i file.mov -f null - 2>error.log. after script is done you may see which files produced error in error.log and why

Answer (score 1):

The looping part is pretty easy, and should look like this :

```
  for x in `find <folder> -name "*.mov"`; do <validate movie file command>; done
```

For the validate file command there's a suitable option in ffmpeg utility which is basically a video converter, but you can convert the input video to NULL and just read input file and report any errors that will appear.

```
 ffmpeg -v error -i ${x} -f null - 2>error.log
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've used the `ffmpeg` command you said with a video that was working, an another that didn't, but both error logs where nearly the same... So I guess this wouldn't work. Anything else I could use?? Thanks!